# How to convert a rails app to a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a ruby on rails app that needs to be gem-ified. Jeweler, helps create basic rubygems. However, how do I package a rails app as a gem? I have a main app that requires my rails app as a gem. I cannot integrate them as the main rails app is to be used as a management app to control smaller apps, running in it as gems/engines.

Comment: Can you describe why you want to package a full application up as a gem? Aren't gems usually plugins or libraries that you can add into apps?

Comment: also do take a look at mountable engines from rails 3.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Rails 3.0 any Rails app is an Engine. For wrap your application to a gem you should:

1. Create new gem with bundler or jeweler or something else.
2. Insert your application code to lib/ directory of your gem.
3. All classes of your app should be in MyGem module, so add MyGem before your class names, like:   Article => MyGem::Article. All your controllers, models, etc. should be namespaced with module GemName.
4. Your file lib/my_gem.rb should contain next code:

   ```
   module MyGem
     class Engine < Rails::Engine; end
   end
   ```

**UPD**

Or be better if you will use mountable engines:

```
$ rails plugin new MyGem
```

It generates mountable engine with dummy app for tests and gemspec.

Comment: hey @alexcoco, is there any way to *reverse* this process? See my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496596/how-to-convert-gem-to-standalone-rails-app