# How to convert a large gem to standalone rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, rubygems

I'm building a social network and have been using the gem community_engine but have been having trouble implementing the large amount of customization that I need for my app. I figure this will make it easier for me to override and add methods, as well as help me to better understand and learn from the code since I will be able to actually see all of it in action.

So far in my attempt I downloaded the source code, added the default bin directory and config files that were missing, as well ass all the gem dependencies.

What else do I need to do to get the app to work? I realize that there may still be a lot and that it might not be easy to explain, but at the very least is there any sort of documentation out there that might help me understand how to convert the gem to a Rails application?

Heres the community_engine repo: https://github.com/bborn/communityengine

Because this idea may draw some criticism, I'll add that I was originally building the app without any huge plugins accept for devise however I'm running out of time to finish this.

More stuff I've tried:

Moving files to a new rails app, got server to run but encountered many seemingly random errors, fixed a few but more just seem to pop up that I cant figure out:

I also took a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html but this gem seems to go beyond that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you clone the gem and begin copying files from the gem into your a new Rails application.

The engine gem probably has a similar structure to a Rails application, so you should be able to move the files from the corresponding folder to the same folder in your Rails root folder.

You may need to move gem files out of modules, change namespaces etc. Relevant folders to look at files you'll want to include might include app/ config/ db/, any gem dependencies in Gemfile or the gemspec file, as well as spec/ or test/.

Beyond that I think there's no silver bullet answer to your question, you're just going to have to work through problems until you have this up and running, and perhaps ask subsequent questions if you hit on an obstacle that you don't get beyond.

Comment: Yep thats what I started doing, I yea I figured that may be the only way I just thought I'd check to see if theres anything out there since they have tutorials and even gems for converting apps to engines. Is there any reason why people don't do this more often? Does it seem like a bad idea for me to do or do you think it will it be fairly difficult? My main reasons for doing this are because I'd like to have all the code together to better understand it and all the code I will write will be on top of or overriding code in the engine.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a way to hook your Rails Engine into a rails app. The [Hooking Into an Application](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#hooking-into-an-application) section of the [Getting Started with Rails Engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) guide should be exactly what you're looking for.

Here are two additional resources on Rails Engines.

[A Guide to Rails Engines in the Wild](http://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-engines-in-the-wild-real-world-examples-of-rails-engines-in-action)

[Rails::Engine - Ruby on Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html)

Comment: But isnt the community_engine gem an engine itself? Or am I confused.

Comment: Ok I think I see what you're talking about, although this isn't exactly what I want to do (unless I'm just confused). From what I've gathered from the rails guide while I would be able to edit the engine source code locally this would still keep the engine files separate from the rest of the app files. If possible I would really like to convert to engine to an app so that it can be run as if the engine never existed. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this not a good idea? I just feel like it will make things much simpler, especially since so much of the apps code would end up being in the engine file. To me it just seems weird to have the apps code either only overriding a bunch of stuff in the engines files, or simply being a projector for the engine files that i have modified.